# Python's "EDIT with IDLE" runs but exits immediately (Win7)

Tags: python, windows-7, contextmenu, python-idle

There are a lot of threads from Python users on Windows who lose the "Edit with IDLE" option on the context menu (right click on a .py file in the File Explorer). I *do* have the menu item, but most of the time it appears to do nothing.

Checking the running applications and processes in Task Manager reveals nothing, except I think IDLE or its launcher or something runs very briefly, so quickly it usually never shows up in the Task Manager list.

Thanks to all who suggested splitting this into question and answer.
My solution (for now) will be posted next

Comment: Can I suggest splitting the above into an actual question and a separate self answer? - People tend to look at Answers rather than at the end of the question when they are looking for an answer and of course many may not look at this because it has __no__ answers.

Comment: Yes post a question and answer yourself. nothing wrong in it. You might even get different (possibly better answers)

Comment: `/W` is not an option for pythonw.exe. That command would immediately fail looking for a file named "/W". Moreover, your registry configuration is wrong if "Edit with IDLE" uses this batch script. That would show a console window. For a system with only Python 2.7, the command in the registry should be `"[Installation Directory]\pythonw.exe" "[Installation Directory]\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw" -e "%1"`.

Comment: eryksun, Thanks for reply. My system is Python 3 only; it has 3.5 installed both by pip and by Anaconda, and it has had 3.6 by Anaconda (now removed). But never 2.x.

/W is a switch to the CMD shell START command. It says that when the script (.BAT file) is complete, the shell should not exit, but keep the window open and wait for input.  I found that here:

Comment: [editor timed out on me] ... I found the /W command documented here:  https://ss64.com/nt/start.html

About the registry: at HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,  Python.File, Shell, editwithidle, shell, edit35, command, I have "F:\Python35\pythonw.exe" -m idlelib "%L" %*

Comment: On my Win10 machine, the same registry key has the same command value (except for the directory containing pythonw.exe).  When I right click a .py file and select 'Edit with IDLE' and then 'Edit with IDLE 3.5 (64 bit), IDLE opens with the file in an editor window.  What happens if in Command Prompt you cd to python file directory and run `py -3.5 -m idlelib myfile.py`?  What is you change `py` to `pyw`?  The latter is equivalent to Edit with IDLE 3.5.  (I am wondering if `pythonw` versus `python` is faulty.)

Answer (score 0):

Eventually it became clear that it was launching IDLE, but IDLE was exiting as soon as it got to the point of waiting for user input. Windows CMD scripts do that sometimes when they aren't feeling conversational.

I found the relevant script at F:\Python35\Lib\idlelib\Idle.bat. If you add a "/W" switch to the command, it waits for input. Problem solved, at least so far. The entire Idle.bat file now reads as follows. The only change was inserting "/W" in the main command line:

@echo off
rem Start IDLE using the appropriate Python interpreter
set CURRDIR=%~dp0
start "IDLE" "%CURRDIR%....\pythonw.exe" /W "%CURRDIR%idle.pyw" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9